# How to convert nested JSON API reponse to dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have one API which returns data for a list something like below:

```
{'NFO:AXISBANK23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9156098, 'last_price': 967.55}, 'NFO:BAJAJ-AUTO23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9156354, 'last_price': 4619.15}, 'NFO:BAJAJFINSV23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9179138, 'last_price': 1544.1}, 'NFO:BAJFINANCE23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9179394, 'last_price': 7390.85}, 'NFO:BALRAMCHIN23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9180930, 'last_price': 395.95}}
```

When I try to convert it to dataframe, primary values goes in header something like below:

```
                  NFO:AXISBANK23JUNFUT  ...  NFO:BALRAMCHIN23JUNFUT
instrument_token            9156098.00  ...              9180930.00
last_price                      967.55  ...                  395.95
```

But I need to have this data available in opposite way as below:

```
                         instrument_token      last_price
NFO:AXISBANK23JUNFUT      9156098               967.55
NFO:BALRAMCHIN23JUNFUT    9180930               395.95
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this
The orient='index' parameter is set to specify that the keys of the dictionary should be used as the index of the DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

api_response = {
'NFO:AXISBANK23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9156098, 'last_price': 967.55},
'NFO:BAJAJ-AUTO23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9156354, 'last_price': 4619.15},
'NFO:BAJAJFINSV23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9179138, 'last_price': 1544.1},
'NFO:BAJFINANCE23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9179394, 'last_price': 7390.85},
'NFO:BALRAMCHIN23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9180930, 'last_price': 395.95}
```

}

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(api_response, orient='index')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First your need to set the keys as index and the other nested data as columns.
You can use the following snippet [Ref: Pandas from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html)

```
samples = {'NFO:AXISBANK23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9156098, 'last_price': 967.55}, 'NFO:BAJAJ-AUTO23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9156354, 'last_price': 4619.15}, 'NFO:BAJAJFINSV23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9179138, 'last_price': 1544.1}, 'NFO:BAJFINANCE23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9179394, 'last_price': 7390.85}, 'NFO:BALRAMCHIN23JUNFUT': {'instrument_token': 9180930, 'last_price': 395.95}}
# Set the dictionary keys as index column and the nesting values as records.
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(samples.values()), index=list(samples.keys()))
```

Answer (score 0):

First I converted into a DF and then used DF Tanspose method to convert this way my data got converted to desired format. and then I can use the script names as index for finding the data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).